# How to configure a GUE receive tunnel in Linux for IPv6

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, iproute, tunneling

I am trying to configure a GUE tunnel to receive IPv6 packets that contain GUE encapped IPv4 packets but I am having trouble de-encapsulating the packets. The IPv6 packets have a GUE encapsulated packet inside of which has a IPv4 packet. I setup a receive tunnel on my end.

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2
modprobe fou
modprobe fou6
ip -6 fou add port 42428 gue -6
ip addr add $VIP/32 dev ip6tnl0
ip -6 link set ip6tnl0 up
```

This is what the resulting ip6tnl0 looks like:

```
4: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1452 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
    inet $VIP/32 scope global ip6tnl0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 $LINK_LOCAL/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On my other machine I can curl the $VIP which is a IPv4 address and on my machine through tcp-dump I can see the encapped packets

```
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
21:32:09.183750 IP6 (hlim 60, next-header UDP (17) payload length: 72) $IPV6_A.53322 > $IPV6_B.42428: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 64
```

So when that UDP packet is decapped properly, I would expect it to contain an IPv4 packet matching the source IPv4 of $VIP. But when I run

```
tcpdump -i any host $VIP -n
```

I do not see anything.

I have repeated this exact same setup for IPv4 (IPv4 packet encapped inside IPv4 packet using GUE) for which the setup for the receive tunnel is similar:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2
modprobe fou
ip fou add port 42428 gue
ip addr add $VIP/32 dev tunl0
ip link set tunl0 up
```

In which case I can see the decapped packets

```
root@ipv4-control:~# tcpdump -i any host $VIP -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
23:12:04.749247 IP $VIP.43830 > $VIP.80: Flags [S], seq 2247712115, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2120453320 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

$VIP above is a virtual ipv4 address that is serving http traffic.

Any ideas what is wrong with the way my IPv6 receive tunnel is setup?

Comment: So in the ipv4 setup I was able to run tcpdump on the tunl0 interface and see the decapped packets in there. However in the ipv6 setup, I don’t see anything on the ip6tnl0 interface. This interface gets added automatically when doing ip -6 fou add port 42428 gue -6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had to set the mode on the ip6tnl0 interface since I was encapsulating IPv4 in IPv6. Doing this did the trick:

```
ip -6 tunnel change ip6tnl0 mode ipip6
```